# AngularFire2 error

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angularfire, angularfire2

I have some trouble with "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7" and "firebase": "^5.0.1".

Every time I launch my Ionic project I have this error :

```
typescript: node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts, line: 5
Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'. Property 'functions' is missing in type 
        'FirebaseApp'. 

   L4:  export declare const FirebaseAppConfigToken: InjectionToken<FirebaseAppConfig>;
   L5:  export declare class FirebaseApp implements firebase.app.App {
   L6:      name: string;
```

Any ideas ? An incompatibility ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to upgrade both of them?
My working versions are the following:

angularfire is : 5.0.0-rc10
firebase is: 5.0.3

as it seems it is very likely that you have some incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

consider using angular 6 .   That might solve your problem